# No Output in Program

Tags: java

A bunch of cities are being stored in an object, which are arranged by an ArrayList structure.

Im trying to run "TrainTimeTable" which is this code :

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrainTimeTable {
private LinkedList<Station> schedule;

public void delay(String station, int minutes) {
    boolean startDelay = false;
    ListIterator<Station> sIt = schedule.listIterator();
    while (sIt.hasNext()) {

        Station currStation = sIt.next();
        if (!startDelay && currStation.getCity().equals(station)) {
            startDelay = true;
        }
        if (startDelay) {
            currStation.delay(minutes);
        }
    }
}

public String getCities() {
    String cities = "";
    for (Station ast : schedule) {
        cities += ast.getCity() + "\n";
    }
    return cities;
}

public void displaySchedule() {
    System.out.printf("%16s\t%8s\t%8s\t%3s\n", "Station", "Arrival",
            "Departure", "Day");
    for (int i = 0; i < schedule.size(); i++) {
        schedule.get(i).displaySchedule();
    }
}

public TrainTimeTable(LinkedList<Station> schedule) {
    super();
    this.schedule = schedule;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    LinkedList<Station> schedule = new LinkedList<Station>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d HH:mm");
    schedule.add(new Station(null, sdf.parse("1 20:30"), "Vancouver"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("2 06:00"), sdf.parse("2 06:35"),
            "Kamloops"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("2 16:00"), sdf.parse("2 17:30"),
            "Jasper"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("2 23:00"), sdf.parse("2 23:59"),
            "Edmonton"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("3 08:00"), sdf.parse("3 08:25"),
            "Saskatoon"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("3 20:45"), sdf.parse("3 22:30"),
            "Winnipeg"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("4 05:02"), sdf.parse("4 05:42"),
            "Sioux Lookout"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("4 15:35"), sdf.parse("4 16:10"),
            "Hornepayne"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("5 00:18"), sdf.parse("5 00:48"),
            "Capreol"));
    schedule.add(new Station(sdf.parse("5 09:30"), null, "Toronto"));

    TrainTimeTable ttt = new TrainTimeTable(schedule);
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cmd = "";
    while (!cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
        System.out.println("Please input command [Quit | Delay | Show]:");
        cmd = inp.next();
        if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Show")) {
            ttt.displaySchedule();
        } else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Delay")) {
            System.out.println("Please input Station to delay:");
            String station = inp.next();
            System.out.println("Please input Minutes to delay:");
            int minutes = inp.nextInt();
            ttt.delay(station, minutes);
        }
    }
    inp.close();
}

}
```

Along with "Station"

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Station {
private Date arrival;
private Date departure;
private String city;

/**
 * @param arrival
 * @param departure
 * @param city
 */
public Station(Date arrival, Date departure, String city) {
    super();
    this.arrival = arrival;
    this.departure = departure;
    this.city = city;
}

public String getArrival() {
    if (arrival == null)
        return "";
    return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(arrival);
}

/**
 * @param arrival
 *            the arrival to set
 */
public void setArrival(Date arrival) {
    this.arrival = arrival;
}

public int getDate() {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    if (departure == null)
        cal.setTime(arrival);
    else
        cal.setTime(departure);

    return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
}

public void displaySchedule() {
    System.out.printf("%16s\t%8s\t%8s\t%3d\n", getCity(), getArrival(),
            getDeparture(), getDate());
}

public void delay(int minutes) {

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    if (arrival != null) {
        cal.setTime(arrival);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        arrival = cal.getTime();
    }
    if (departure != null) {
        cal.setTime(departure);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        departure = cal.getTime();
    }
}

public String getDeparture() {
    if (departure == null)
        return "";
    return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(departure);
}

/**
 * @param departure
 *            the departure to set
 */
public void setDeparture(Date departure) {
    this.departure = departure;
}

/**
 * @return the city
 */
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

/**
 * @param city
 *            the city to set
 */
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

}
```

I am using Netbeans as an IDE, there doesn't show to be any errors, but I don't understand why it isn't running. I think it is something small that I am over looking.

Comment: Fire up the debugger and step through it, then report back.

Comment: Are you typing anything at the prompt?

Comment: It seems to work for me. I have the Scanner well waiting for the command. Maybe you changed the class name or the package name and NetBean didn't recognize the main. Check the main class used on the project panel.

Comment: @nicomp I fired up the debugger with nothing showing being wrong.

Comment: @cricket_007 When I try to compile TrainTimeTable.Java in cmd I get this :       TrainTimeTable.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
                private LinkedList<Station> schedule;
                           ^
     symbol:   class Station
  location: class TrainTimeTable
TrainTimeTable.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
        public TrainTimeTable(LinkedList<Station> schedule) {
                                         ^

Comment: @DjoryKrache Yeah I tried to compile them using cmd, and still with no avail nothing is showing, scanner isnt appearing or waiting for a response. Thanks !

Comment: I recommend you use an IDE rather than trying to compile at the command line

Comment: @R-Nation If you don't have an IDE how in the world did use a debugger?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry I didn't make it clear, I am using an IDE - Netbeans exactly, But for some reason when I run it through there all I get is " run: " with no output :( I have no idea what I am doing wrong, as I tried running other programs and they work just fine. The reason I used cmd was to try and see if it works compiling it through there. Thanks !

Comment: @nicomp Sorry I wasn't clear, I am using an IDE, but its not working. All I get is  " run:" with no output when I try running it from Netbeans, so I tried via cmd hoping it would work, but still nothing. Thank you!

Comment: @DjoryKrache Currently I have my files all in order in the right hierarchy, and I tried to compile other programs and those work, but this one just push's out errors, I feel like an idiot cause I cant figure this out :(

Comment: Your error on the command line is that you are probably missing a classpath, therefore any other class file won't compile with the others.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you so much, Im sorry Im fairly new, but what would be your suggestions to get this running? Should I move things around? Is there any way I can isolate just this program to make sure it works? I have to get this done by the end of the day, and the stress is on to say the least. The part which I dont understand is that why my other programs compile just fine, but this one is being like that. Thanks again!!

Comment: @R-Nation that's because, your program need the Station file in order to work. That's why, you should put them in another project and the -sourcepath is mandatory when you have to compile more than one file. I guess the other file were just single file with main application. Now, you use two files, I guessed that because you can't have two public class in the same file in Java.

Comment: @DjoryKrache I compiled both files, now when I run them with the "
.java" command, I get "could not find or load main class" for both of them. I have them both in the same folder, in a different package on their own. Thanks again for the continued help!!

Comment: @DjoryKrache After I did that, I still got the error when trying to run it from cmd. Is there a certain way I need to call it so they run both at once to work? Now I went back into my IDE and its running from my IDE now once compiled it the way you said. Thank you!

Comment: You need to `javac` all necessary files. Then you need to `java -cp . MainClass`, where MainClass is the class from the java file with the main method. `-cp .` sets the classpath to the current folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compile in command line, In the root of your project , you compile using :

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src src/TrainTimeTable.java
```

I admit that you put your files in the folder src and you have a folder bin.

Now, you can go in the folder bin and run

```
java TrainTimeTable
```

Note 1: src is the folder containing all your *.java files.

Note 2: bin or out or target is the folder that will contained all your *.class files.